# How to check if the data in my Firebase database matches my TextView.toString in Java?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, match

Essentially, I am creating an alarm clock that only allows you to turn off your alarm if you scan a barcode whose value has been entered into my Firebase database under the child "content". What I have at the moment is a scanner that scans the code and displays this value on a TextView contentTxt in the Android app.

When I click the "checkButton", it is supposed to take this TextView change it toString and then run through the database to check if there is any value that matches it. If there is, it will stop the alarm. If there isn't, it will display the notification that "This is not a scanned barcode". However, even though the values in my firebase are the same as that in my TextView, it only ever says it's not a scanned barcode.

Here is my code:

```
            final Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkBtn);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("barcodes").orderByChild("content")
                        .equalTo(contentTxt.toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                            // method that alters update text TextBox
                            set_alarm_text("Alarm off!");

                            // cancel the alarm
                            alarm_manager.cancel(pending_intent);

                            // put in extra string into my_intent, telling the clock that "Alarm Off" was pressed
                            my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm off");

                            // stop the ringtone
                            sendBroadcast(my_intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "This is not a scanned barcode!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is a screenshot of my Firebase also, if that helps:

[image: Screenshot showing my database's hierarchy and children]

There is no actual error codes or crashes coming up in my code, it just continually says there are no same values, and then I can't get the damn alarm to turn off.

As is my understanding, I have pointed my code to the child "barcodes" and ordered by its child "content", provided it is equalTo my contentTxt.toString. To me, that sounds like it should isolate that value and see if it has any value at all, so perhaps you can enlighten me. I have even tried experimenting with changing dataSnapshot.hasChildren() to .exists() etc., but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to comment that I fixed the problem. Instead of `contentTxt.toString()`, I should have used `contentTxt.getText().toString()`. Stupid mistake, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dataSnapshot.hasChildren()`, try `dataSnapshot.exists()`.

Comment: I tried that as well but unfortunately it still runs the else code. Even looking at the textview and then the db, the strings are the exact same, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.